# c++ wcf client duplex

Tags: c++, wcf

I have a WCF service that uses duplex contracts via a netTCP binding.  It's basically a chat server that relays the messages it receives to the connected clients.  The service, and the C# client work great.

What I want to do is create an unmanaged C++ client for the service.  Is this possible?  And if so, how is this achieved?

I'm ok with using 3rd party libraries, just no .Net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the little-known WWS - Windows Web Services. This is basically WCF but native code. Its much smaller in size and much faster - [MSDN magazine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee335693.aspx) shows some benchmarks (yeah, ok) that say WWS handling SOAP is faster than WCF's Net.TCP. WWS net.tcp calls are several times faster than WCF :)

WWS also runs with a much reduced working set, 500kb vs 4.5mb for the simplest of simple services.

That link has sample code for you.

I think you get this library for free in Windows 7. You can get it for XP as a [separate download](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wndp/archive/2009/10/09/final-version-of-windows-web-services-api-for-windows-xp-vista-server-2003-and-server-2008-is-now-available.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the article was very informative. There are two things I'm still unclear on though. First, the article doesn't specifically state that WWS supports callback contracts for duplex communication.  The other thing is that while WWS is written in native code, it doesn't seem to be cross platform: 'WWS will use WinHTTP, HTTP.sys, or Winsock, depending on the selected transport'
Basically I'd like to be able to create a cross platform client for my WCF chat service.

Comment: ah well, you should have said you wanted cross-platform. However, I thought there was a clue in that you're using netTCP. It doesn't interoperate. End of story. You'll have to use something different - the only interoperable protocol WCF supports is SOAP, and SOAP 1.1 at that as 1.2 has some 'interpretation of standards' issues that make it less than useful working with Java and PHP SOAP clients. So - if you want cross platform, start with a cross-platform system. I can recommend ZeroMQ which has C# bindings as well as C, but any other RPC system will do.

Comment: Sorry, should have stated that in my question.  So, looks like if I want cross platform I will have to start from scratch.  I've been looking around, and I think I will give [RCF](http://www.deltavsoft.com/index.html) a try.